# How to resolve 'import javafx cannot be resolved' in VSCode?

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-code, ant

I am working on a simple program of JavaFX, HelloFX. I execute tasks like building or launching with ant. I have zero problems with that, it works perfectly so the code and the libraries are well linked in build.xml as you can see in the code.

But, VSCode does not find JavaFX and says 'import javafx cannot be resolved'. So I am wondering how does VSCode find Java dependencies? And how could he find the JavaFX one, As ant does? I thought that VSCode uses build.xml to find dependencies so, maybe I am wrong, or maybe my build.xml is bad.

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
<project name="HelloFX" basedir="." default="rebuild-run">



<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="lib.dir"     value="/home/rafael/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib"/>
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<property name="build.dir"   value="bin"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

<property name="main-class"  value="${ant.project.name}"/>


<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" modulepath="/home/rafael/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib">
        <compilerarg line="--add-modules javafx.controls"/> 
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}"  modulepath="/home/rafael/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib" >
        <jvmarg line="--add-modules javafx.controls"/>
        <sysproperty key="java.library.path" path="$(lib.dir)"/>
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="rebuild" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="rebuild-run" depends="clean,run"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSCode Task to run ant buildfile located anywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958496/vscode-task-to-run-ant-buildfile-located-anywhere)

Comment: This will help you: [JavaFX-11 with VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349894/javafx-11-with-vscode/54353065#54353065)

Comment: @JoséPereda I already had a look to a lot of posts and none is solving my problem. This one is using Eclipse .classpath file and I want to use build.xml file with ant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Ant extension for VSCode, named [Ant Target Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nickheap.vscode-ant).

Once you install it, you can open your JavaFX project that contains a `build.xml` file at the root directory.

I was able to modify a little bit your build above, in order to add a `run` target, and run `HelloFX` from [here](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/IDE/IntelliJ/Non-Modular/Java).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="HelloFX" default="default" basedir="." xmlns:fx="javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant">

<property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="lib.dir"     value="/Users/user/Downloads/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib"/>
<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<property name="build.dir"   value="bin"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

<property name="main-class"  value="hellofx.Main"/>

<property environment="env"/>
<target name="clean">
    <!-- Verify that JDK is 11+ -->
    <echo message="JAVA_HOME is set to = ${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath" modulepath="/Users/user/Downloads/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib">
        <compilerarg line="--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"/> 
    </javac>
    <copy todir="${classes.dir}">
    <fileset dir="src"
             includes="**/*.fxml,**/*.properties,**/*.css" />
</copy>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true" modulepath="/Users/user/Downloads/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib" jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar">
        <jvmarg line="--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"/> 
    </java>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
</project>
```

Every time you modify the file and save it, the ant target panel is reloaded and the targets show up:

[image: VSCode with Ant]

If you run any of the targets, the output is shown in the terminal.

Make sure you have JDK 11+ selected (I've added an echo to the `clean` target). If that is not the case, you can set it directly from the same terminal (`export JAVA_HOME=...`).

Then you can run the `run` target and get the app working:

[image: Running Ant from VSCode]

Note that while this works fine, it will be more convenient to use build tools like Maven or Gradle.

Getting the IDE to use the JavaFX library

By default, you will get a warning message [`Classpath is incomplete`](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/wiki/%22Classpath-is-incomplete%22-warning), and there is no autocompletion for JavaFX classes.

Since VSCode is expecting a Maven `pom.xml` or an Eclipse `.classpath` file, I'm going to add the latter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="bin/classes" path="src/">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="false"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/user/Downloads/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib/javafx.base.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/user/Downloads/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib/javafx.graphics.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/user/Downloads/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib/javafx.controls.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/user/Downloads/javafx-sdk-12.0.1/lib/javafx.fxml.jar"/>

    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-12">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
</classpath>
```

And that seems to solve the issues with JavaFX syntax and autocompletion. Note that this might require installing Eclipse.

[image: JavaFX syntax]

Finally you can add the same `launcher.json` as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54353065/3956070), so you can run the app directly, without the ant tasks (though I take this isn't your goal).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your complete answer. However, I was having a lot of trouble with ant and VSCode, as I want to use TestFX also. So now I am trying Eclipse and Maven.

Comment: Not only build tools (Maven/Gradle) really help in your projects, but also traditional Java IDEs and new ones (like VSCode) are no longer keeping ant builds updated. So it is advisable to move to build tools as soon as possible...

Answer (score -1):

Press `ctrl+shift+p` and then type "clean java language server workspace", hit enter, and then click reload and delete on bottom right of vscode, this will make the language server rebuild our dependencies.

Worked great for me

Comment: Just fyi tried this and it didn't work so its' not a silver bullet.